# How do I remove all of my indents in Word?

Tags: microsoft-word

My document has about 65000 words, and I made a lot of inconsistent indents as I was writing it.  Now I'm going back and flushing it all to the beginning of the line.  Is there a way to remove all this whitespace quickly?

Comment: How did you do the indents in the first place? Did you set the margins on the ruler, or did you use tabs? If the latter, did you set the tabs, or did you use the defaults?

Comment: Unfortunately, I was on a mobile phone most of the time, and just instinctively added a few spaces.  I didn't even do it consistently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### You should never use spaces for formatting or indenting.

First, do a repeated search-and-replace across the whole document for `"  "` (two spaces), replacing with nothing at all, until there is nothing found.

Then, do another search and replace for a paragraph mark followed by a space - I *think* that the search expression is `'^p '`; you'll want to check the Word special characters - and replace it with a paragraph mark *without* the space.

In the future, use the indent/margins functions on the ruler, or set up and use some styles. That way, you'll get consistency, and you won't be trying to treat Word like it was an old mechanical typewriter.

Comment: +1 for *trying to treat Word like...an old mechanical typewriter.*